# Uniform convergence $f_n(x)=\frac{nx+n^2x^2}{1+n^2x^2}$

Tags: uniform-convergence

An example in my textbook is as follows.
Determine the limit $f(x)$ of the sequence $f_n(x)$ where
$$f_n(x)=\frac{nx+n^2x^2}{1+n^2x^2},\quad n=1,2,3,...$$
Also determine if the convergence $f_n \longrightarrow f$ is uniform.

The solution states that it is clear that $f_n(x) \longrightarrow x$ as $n\longrightarrow \infty$. However by my calculations (and wolframalpha) $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)=1$??? What am I doing wrong?

The solution then continues with
$$f_n(x)-f(x)=\frac{nx+n^2x^2}{1+n^2x^2}-x={\frac{(n-1)x}{1+n^2x^2}}.$$

Once again by my calculations
$$f_n(x)-f(x)=\frac{nx+n^2x^2}{1+n^2x^2}-x=\frac{nx+n^2x^2-x-n^2x^3}{1+n^2x^2}.$$
I have no idea how the final equality simplifies to $\frac{(n-1)x}{1+n^2x^2}$? Any help gratefully accepted.

Comment: I can only think of an error in the statement and the highest order term in the numerator is $x^3$, rather than $x^2$. Then the proposed solution would be consistent...

Comment: That must be it Miguel. Thank you, I nearly went mad trying to figure out what I was doing wrong. I will take it up with the professor on Monday, he wrote the textbook ; ) .